# Configure postfix to forward a single final destination address to an external relay host

Tags: postfix, domain-name

I have a Postfix server that manages internal mail, being the final destination for the organization domain. Anyway the external SMTP for the domain is managed by the ISP server. The messages are then dispatched to internal users mailboxes by fetchmail.
Since one of the users receives the email also on its phone, fetchmail leaves a copy of messages on that user's folder, in order to let the phone client read it.
In this way, when a client inside the organization sends an email to that user, the message is dispatched internally and the phone does not receive it.
Is there a way to force postfix to use an external relay host for a single address whose domain is the final destination for the server?

Answer (score 0):

By using the `transport` table it is possible to define the smtp nexthop host to be used for delivery of messages for a specific address.
`transport` table shall be enabled in main.cf file with directive:

```
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
```

To route email for a single address to a specific relay host the following line shall be present in `transport` table:

```
someone@internaldomain.ext    smtp:external.relay.com
```

or, alternatively, the following line:

```
someone@internaldomain.ext    :[external.relay.com]
```

where the transport protocol is omitted and left to `postfix` to define the correct one based on the address class (smtp in this case).

Sources:
http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#transport_maps
http://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html
`man 5 transport`